# Repeat footnote every page

Tags: footnotes

I am using the footmisc package to reference for footnotes. The problem I have is that when I refer to a footnote on a different page, latex does not reproduce the footnote on that page, I want it to reproduce it so that there is no need to return to that page to see the footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Example\footnote{\label{test}Some footnote}
\newpage
Example\footref{test}
\end{document}
```

For example, the above text creates a document with 2 pages and I want the footnote to appear on every page. Here I have forced a new page, but in my document, a page break can happen anywhere.

Comment: it seems that you do not want a _reference_  simply use `\newcommand\footnoteA{\footnote{some footnote}}`  and then use `\footnoteA` whenever you need a copy of that note.

Comment: If ever I use `\footnoteA` on the same page, will that note create two similar foonotes ?

Comment: yes, it would .

Comment: That would be redundant then, what I want is that if its on the same page, it reuses an existing footnote with a label and if ever an existing footnote is referenced on a different page, it recreates it

Comment: That's possible but I don't know of any off-the shelf package that offers that and is more code than I have time to suggest in  an answer today, but someone may answer (or know of a package that does that already).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the help, i've found a different to write my text so I don't depend on this, i'll let the question here so that someone may answer it if there know any solution and that may benefit others

Comment: The `fixfoot` package (included in TeXLive, I don't know about other TeX distributions) does this, but the documentation is rather sparse!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

The basic idea is to make custom `\footnote` and `\footref` macros. The custom `\footnote` macro saves the current page number and footnote text before inserting the footnote. Then the custom `\footref` checks whether the current page is different to the page the footnote first appears on. If it's different, it inserts a new footnote with the right number, otherwise it just inserts the reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{footmisc}
% temporary counter to save footnote number
\newcounter{foottmpcnt}
% custom \footnote command
% #1: label
% #2: footnote text
\newcommand{\myfootnote}[2]{%
  \csgdef{footnote@text@#1}{#2}%
  \global\newcounter{footnote@page@#1}%
  \setcounter{footnote@page@#1}{\value{page}}%
  \footnote{\label{#1}#2}}
% custom \footref command
% #1: label
\newcommand{\myfootref}[1]{%
  \footref{#1}%
  \ifnumcomp{\value{footnote@page@#1}}{=}{\value{page}}
    {}
    {\setcounter{foottmpcnt}{\value{footnote}}%
     \setcounter{footnote}{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
     \footnotetext{\csuse{footnote@text@#1}}%
     \setcounter{footnote}{\value{foottmpcnt}}%
     \setcounter{footnote@page@#1}{\value{page}}}}
\begin{document}
Example\myfootnote{testa}{Some footnote}

Example\myfootnote{testb}{Some footnote}

Example\myfootref{testa}
\newpage
Example\myfootnote{testc}{Some footnote}

Example\myfootref{testa}

Example\myfootnote{testd}{Some footnote}

Example\myfootref{testc}

Example\myfootref{testa}
\newpage
Example\myfootref{testa}

Example\myfootref{testc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What changes should I make to your code if I want the same footnote at every page but without and numbering or a marker?

Comment: @Alice, only I see these comments. You are best to ask a new question with a new MWE and link back to this answer as part of your explanation. That way more people will see your question.