# Repeat a footnote explaining multiple citations?

Tags: footnotes

In my LaTeX report, I discuss *A Big Concept*:

```
Here is the main body of the report.
Blah blah blah A Big Concept\footnote
{%
   A well known description is provided in Reference
   \cite{reference_A} while Reference \cite{Reference_B}
   provides a lighter (and possibly less permanent) treatment.
   \label{fnBigConcept}
}
blah blah blah.  Appendix \ref{AppBigConcept} discusses this in
more detail.

<...snip...>

\appendix

\section{Details of A Big Concept} \ref{AppBigConcept}

Here is the discussion on A Big Concept \cite{reference_A}.
Blah blah blah.
```

The footnote in the main body of the report explains two
references.  In the appendix, I only cite only one reference
because it seems wrong to repeat the footnote.  However, I think
that the explanation in the footnote helps in both places.

In the appendix, I could reference the footnote in the main body,
but I would want a phrase like "See footnote \ref{fnBigConcept} on
page \pageref{fnBigConcept}".  That's a mouthful, so I would want
to tuck it away into its own footnote.  But that starts to get out
of hand -- a footnote to refer the reader to a footnote on another
page.  It's not much better than repeating the footnote, which would
actually be more convenient for the reader.

**What is the best way to actually provide the explanation of the
two citations so that it is conveniently accessible in multiple
locations in the document?**

If the best solution is to repeat the foonote, I will manaully
retype the footnote.  This [automatic repetition
scheme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447677/repeat-footnote-every-page)
seems like a lot of work.  *Afternote:* I ended up using David Carlisle's `\newcommand\footnoteA{\footnote{some footnote}\:}` from the above webpage -- until such time that it is determined that one should *not* to repeat footnotes. In the preceding code, I found that `\:` was needed to prevent abutment with the following text.