# How to repeat the same footnote on different page with the same footnote number?

Tags: overleaf, latex3

I am trying to repeat the same footnote on different pages with the same footnote number but failed. This is the example obtained from here `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447677/repeat-footnote-every-page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Example\footnote{\label{test}Some footnote}
\newpage
Example\footref{test}
\end{document}
```

But the  main problem is its just give me only a footnote number in the other page and it is not inserting the actual footnote. Please I need your help on this. Actually I want the same copy of the footnote to appear in another page. Thank you

Comment: that sounds wrong. Why do you want to repeat the number *and* the text. Imho only the one or the other makes sense.

Comment: You could take a look at the [`multifootnote`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multifootnote) package. It covers some of you're wanted features.

Answer (score 0):

It is still a bad idae, but it can be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}% or hyperref

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savefoot}[2]{% #1=label, #2=text
  \footnote{#2}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\thefootnote}%
  \edef\@currentlabelname{#2}%
  \label{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\repeatfoot}[1]{% #1 = label
  \footnote[\getrefnumber{#1}]{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{??}}}

\begin{document}
Example\savefoot{test}{Some footnote}
\newpage
Example\repeatfoot{test}
\end{document}
```